# Verify title of tooltip using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, tooltip

How to get title of tooltip using selenium webdriver[image: This is html code for tooltip]

My code is:

```
starred = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='headerStarButton']/span"));
builder = new Actions(driver);
mouseover = builder.clickAndHold(starred).build();
mouseover.perform();
String title= starred.getAttribute("title");
System.out.println("title::" + title);
```

Comment: And, what's the exception?

Comment: Couldnt see `title` attribute for given `span`.

Comment: So probably tooltip is not loaded?

Answer (score 0):

This would be because the tooltip is not there. To get a tooltip to render, it renders the text in the Title attribute. you are looking to the title attribute but it is not contained in your xPath lookup.

You would need it to be:

```
<span class"ico ico12 tip-below star-g-12 find-tooltip tooltipstered" title="Tooltip text here"></span>
```

It would then work since the title attribute is located in your xPath lookup.